# Order in named capture groups

Tags: regex, perl

I recently discovered the power of named capture groups in regexp. Unfortunately it seems I cannot use them in different order.

Let's consider this short price list:

```
 15 USD
 CHF 18
```

I would like to retrieve the currency and its value. So, I naively wrote this:

```
(?|
(?<value>\d+)\s*(?<currency>[a-z]+)
|
(?<currency>[a-z]+)\s*(?<value>\d+)
)
```

Unfortunately as visible here (https://regex101.com/r/uE8qE1/1), the regex has errors. However, I don't get any errors in Perl and I can access `$+{currency}` and `$+{value}` but I sometime get the currency into the value and vice versa.

Is there any way to capture mixed up elements in stings?

**EDIT**

Here's an example in Perl that shows the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;

my $_ = "14 USD
CHF 15";

while(/(?|
(?<value>[0-9]+)\s*(?<currency>[a-z]+)
|
(?<currency>[a-z]+)\s*(?<value>[0-9]+)
)/igmx) {
    say "Currency: $+{currency}\tValue: $+{value}";
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./test.pl
Currency: USD   Value: 14
Currency: 15    Value: CHF
```

Comment: @mpapec Yeah it makes sense but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: You would do better to test using Perl, as there is a possibility that PHP's implementation of PCRE isn't identical

Comment: https://eval.in/232768 get rid of `(?| ..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the branch reset pattern is confusing the regex engine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /(?<value>\d+)\s*(?<currency>[a-z]+) | (?<currency>[a-z]+)\s*(?<value>\d+)/ix;
  say "$+{value} $+{currency}";
}

__DATA__
15 USD
CHF 18
```

**output**

```
15 USD
18 CHF
```

---

**Update**

`@PatrickJ.S.` helped enormously by pointing out that this very situation is documented in [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) under *"Extended Patterns"*. The section on *branch reset* says this. The bolding is my own.

> Be careful when using the branch reset pattern in combination with named captures. Named captures are implemented as being aliases to numbered groups holding the captures, and that interferes with the implementation of the branch reset pattern. **If you are using named captures in a branch reset pattern, it's best to use the same names, in the same order, in each of the alternations**

As far as I can tell there is no mention anywhere of the behaviour when there are multiple named captures with the same name, so even if you get this working as you expect you are on very shaky ground.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for anyone trying to use capturing groups that match in any order (especially named capturing groups), is to do the capturing in look-aheads:

[[See it working here]](http://tpcg.io/MY7ADA)

```
use 5.014;

$_ = "
CHF 15
14 USD
";

while(/(?=.*?\b(?<value>[0-9]+)\b)(?=.*?\b(?<currency>[a-z]+)\b)/igmx) {
    say "Currency: $+{currency}\tValue: $+{value}";
}
```

results in

```
Currency: CHF   Value: 15
Currency: USD   Value: 14
```